# Hidden Input/Textarea value onChange setState in React - without user typing inputs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-lifecycle

I need to **trigger a function** when the value of **Hidden input**/textArea/TextField changing in **React**. Not when the user enter values. When dynamically changing the hidden input value trigger a function.

```
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

class RowComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      xx: "",
      salary: 0,
    };
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      xx: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const {
      member: { salary },
    } = this.props;

    console.log(this.state.xx);

    return (
      <TextField
        name="HiddenField"
        type="hidden"
        value={this.state.salary !== 0 ? this.state.salary : salary}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How is the hidden input changed?

Comment: By changing the input value `value={this.state.salary !== 0 ? this.state.salary : salary}` :)

Comment: Then, why you need a onchange for the input? Might be better to watch for changes on `this.state.salary` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onChange` will not trigger here because it will only fire when the user changes the value of the input field (e.g., user types in a new character).

Based on the logic of your app, It looks like the `value` of `TextField` will **only** be controlled by the prop as long as the `RowComponent` salary state is not equal to `0` (based off of this condition on your `TextField`: `value={this.state.salary !== 0 ? this.state.salary : salary}`) - and this is evident and is much more clear when you browse the state/props with React Dev Tools.

So, what you can do is compare the previous props & state with the current ones & assess whether or not to update the state `xx`

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevProps.member.salary !== this.props.member.salary) {
    if (this.state.salary === 0) {
      this.setState(
        {
          xx: this.props.member.salary
        },
        () => {
          console.log("new xx", this.state.xx);
        }
      );
    }
  }

  if (prevState.salary !== this.state.salary) {
    this.setState(
      {
        xx: this.state.salary
      },
      () => {
        console.log("new xx", this.state.xx);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit fragrant-sun-eivqq]